# $f (x,y) = { \frac{\Gamma(p_1+p_2+p_3) }{\Gamma(p_1) \Gamma(p_2) \Gamma (p_3) }} x^{p_1-1} y^{p_2-1 }(1-x-y)^{p_3-1}$

Tags: random-variables

For the bivariate beta RV $(X,Y)$ with PDF 
$f (x,y) = { \frac{\Gamma(p_1+p_2+p_3) }{\Gamma(p_1) \Gamma(p_2) \Gamma (p_3) }} x^{p_1-1} y^{p_2-1 }(1-x-y)^{p_3-1} 
, x \ge 0 , y \ge 0$ and $x + y \le 1$ ,

where $p_1, p_2$, and $p_3$ are positive real numbers. find the marginal PDFs of $X$ and $Y $and the conditional PDFs. Find also the conditional PDF of $\frac{Y}{(1-X)}$, given $X = x$.

My claim is that $X$ follows $ \text{Beta}(p_1,p_2+p_3)$, But I can't prove this.

Comment: When you write "Bin", do you mean Beta?

Comment: Yes,  I edited my post

Comment: Are you sure that is meant to be a sum of gamma function in the denominator, rather than a product?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I forgot to edit

Comment: $f$ is the two dimensional Dirichlet distribution. It's marginals are well known to be Beta distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for $0\leq z\leq 1$ and $b>0, c>0$ we have:
$$\int_0^{z} y^{b-1} (z-y)^{c-1}\mathrm d y = \dfrac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c) z^{b+c-1}}{\Gamma(b+c)}$$

So for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $p_1,p_2,p_3\in\Bbb R^+$

$$\int_0^{1-x} \dfrac{\Gamma(p_1+p_2+p_3)x^{p_1-1}y^{p_2-1} (1-x-y)^{p_3-1}}{\Gamma(p_1)\Gamma(p_2)\Gamma(p_3)}\mathrm d y = \dfrac{\Gamma(p_1+p_2+p_3) x^{p_1-1}(1-x)^{p_2+p_3-1}}{\Gamma(p_1)\Gamma(p_2+p_3)}$$

Which is the probability density function for $\mathcal{Beta}(p_1,p_2+p_3)$

---

**Note:** that requires the denominator to be a product of gamma functions rather than a sum, as I suspect you should have.

Comment: What about the conditional pdf of $X$, and that of $\frac{Y}{1-X}$

Comment: $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) =\dfrac{ f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$, and so $f_{Y/(1-X)\mid X}(z\mid x) = \dfrac{(1-x)\,f_{X,Y}(x,z(1-x))}{f_X(x)}$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second one that is can you show that  $\frac{Y}{1-X} $ follows $\text{Beta}(p_{2},p_{3})$?